# URL first SSRS parameter not affect to report

Tags: url, ssrs-2008

All parameters transferred to URL are transferred to the report, except the first one. Date is taken by default.

`http://s7bi.group.s7/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f...%8f&rs:rp_DateBeg=21/07/2019&rp_DateEnd=05/08/2019&rp_APCode=SIP&rp_isUTC=UTC&rp_FlightNumber=913;264`

rp_DateBeg is ignore by report

How can I set DateBeg parameter directly coming from URL

[image]
How to pass right date from url to parameter?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to pass right date from url to parameter?

Comment: can you change culture value from url like below?

´//myrshost/Reportserver?/SampleReports/Product+Line+Sales&rs:Command=Render&StartDate=4/10/2008&EndDate=11/10/2008&rs:ParameterLanguage=de-DE´

Comment: Command=Render& - helped! Thanks!

Comment: @Svetlana I will add this as answer. This will helps others as well. Do mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you change culture value from url like below?

`rs:Command=Render` this might help as well.

//myrshost/Reportserver?/SampleReports/Product+Line+Sales&rs:Command=Render&StartDate=4/10/2008&EndDate=11/10/2008&rs:ParameterLanguage=de-DE